# linking a separate .js file in Brackets text editor

Tags: javascript, html, brackets

Im using Brackets text editor to add some javascript to an HTML file. everything works ok when I add the javascript directly into the HTML file between  tags, however it no longer works when I try to create a separate .js file and then link it to my HTML. it gives all these error codes to my .js file.

Even the jQuery file that I downloaded and added to my project it says is full of errors. However when I link my HTML to jQuery hosted on google, the whole web page works even though my own main.js shows error messages. Why will it work with a link to jQuery from google but not jQuery in a local file?

I've copied code directly from an online tutorial as well so I know its correct, and it still doesn't do anything.

What am I missing?

Here's a picture of my html head and main.js document with file tree on the side [image]

Comment: @MaxBaldwin If it's a duplicate, why not flag it?

Comment: @Luca because I didn't know how to... Now I do: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118124/where-on-earth-is-the-mark-duplicate-ui